# How to make Pods admin array value dynamic in php?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using pods admin plugin and I want to change the value in array. raspored.meta_value are days from 0-6 or from Sunday to Monday.

I want that the value in raspored.meta_value = "dynamic" is changing how the days are going.

Btw: I'm new and not so good in English.Hope you understand :)

```
$params = array( 'limit' => -1, 'where' => 'raspored.meta_value = "4"' ); 
        $pods = pods( 'raspored', $params ); 
        if ( $pods->total() > 0 ) { 
            while( $pods->fetch() )  { 

                //reset id 
                $pods->id = $pods->id(); 

                //get the template 
                $temp = $pods->template( 'Probni' ); 
                //output template if it exists 
                if ( isset( $temp )  ) { 
                    echo $pods->display( 'some_other_field' ); 
                    echo $temp; 
                }
            } 
            //pagination 
            echo $pods->pagination(); 
        } 
        else { 
            echo 'No content found.'; 
        }
```

Comment: Can you format your post, that it looks nicer?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: Please post your code *as text* here, not as image.

Comment: @deceze I did now sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I added if statement and change the array value for "where clause".

Example:

```
$params = array( 'limit' => -1, 'where' => 'raspored.meta_value = "1"', 'orderby' => 'vrijeme_start ASC' );
        if (date("l") === "Monday") {
            $params["where"] = array ('1');
        }
        elseif (date("l") === "Tuesday") {
            $params["where"] = array ('2');
        }
        elseif (date("l") === "Wednesday") {
            $params["where"] = array ('3');
        }
        elseif (date("l") === "Thursday") {
            $params["where"] = array ('4');
        }
        elseif (date("l") === "Friday") {
            $params["where"] = array ('5');
        }
        elseif (date("l") === "Saturday") {
            $params["where"] = array ('6');
        }
        elseif (date("l") === "Sunday") {
            $params["where"] = array ('0');
        }

        else {
            echo 'Nema sadržaja';
        }
```

Hope somebody will need this :)